# to the left and the right a div to centered div

Tags: html, css

Hello i'm  using a div for content thats centered

```
   <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> content</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:`

```
.wrapper 
{
    width:1000px;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin:10px auto;

}

.container
{
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
    background:#fff;
    float:left;

}
```

now I want to place at the right and left border to the centered div two divs with a fixed height and width and i want to keep the class container centered. How can I do this.

Comment: So you want to have keep .container centered, but e.g. left column would be wider than right?

Comment: How is the .container centered? Seems to be floated left.

Comment: Consider re-wording this.  Hard to follow the question.

Comment: @user1829716 - probably drawing would best option

Answer (score 2):

You can define two style using `float:left` and `float:right` to set div on the side (inside the .wrapper), you should consider removing the `float:left` from .container class

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare `<!Doctype html>` in your HTML CODE `<!Doctype html><head></head><body></body></html>`
2. You NEW CSS:

   `.wrapper 
   {
   width:100%;
   min-height:200px;
   margin:10px;
   }`

   `.container
   {
   width:70%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background:#fff;
   }`

And ready.

I created this example `jsfiddle.net/8D7Yd`

Saludos
rebocano.com

Answer (score 0):

You should really rewrite your question. 
If this is what you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/